# Process started with QProcess::startDetached is still a child and killed when parent quits

Tags: windows, qt

I'm trying to get my auto-updater to work for my Qt 5.1 project (running on Windows 7 32 bit). It downloads an installer, starts it and quits itself. The problem is that when the application quits, the installer is killed along with it, regardless of the fact that the process is started detached.

This is the code in question.

```
QScopedPointer<QTemporaryFile> installerFile(new QTemporaryFile());
installerFile->setFileTemplate(QDir::tempPath() + "/Setup_XXXXXX.exe");
installerFile->setAutoRemove(false);

if (installerFile->open())
{
    installerFile->write(setupDownloadReply->readAll());
    installerFile->close();
    QString filename = installerFile->fileName();
    installerFile.reset(); // Delete the object Otherwise Windows doesn't release it.

    // Neither of these two options actually start a non-child process
    bool started = QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filename));
    //bool started = QProcess::startDetached(filename);

    if (started)
    {
        if (!toVersion.isEmpty())
            settings.setValue(SETTINGS_UPDATING_TO, toVersion);

        QApplication::quit();
    }
}
```

Sysinternals process explorer shows that the started installer is actually a child of the program starting it, even when I do `openUrl`. I find this really bizarre.

If I use `mainwindow->close()` instead of `QApplication::quit()`, the window disappears, but the process keeps hanging. And then, the installer can't overwrite the locked files.

So, how do I really start a detached process? Is there a similar way to how Linux parents orphaned processes to init?

Answer (score 1):

I can partly answer my own question. It was quite simple: the behaviour only occurred when debugging, not when running normally.

As for the other part of the problem, the hanging process causing the files to remain locked: for some reason, it doesn't do that anymore... Even when I install the old version again...